# shield (invalidate) assert in python

Tags: python, assert, invalidation, ndebug

I want to invalidate the "assert" in my Python codes when I run it as a release edition. Consider that a lot of "assert" may be used in my files in the developing procedure, but I want to skip the compiling of "assert" to enhance the efficiency. Is there some simple method like a pre_define of "NDEBUG" in c++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command line option `-O`. As described in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement):

> In the current implementation, the built-in variable `__debug__` is `True`
>   under normal circumstances, False when optimization is requested
>   (command line option `-O`). The current code generator emits no code for
>   an assert statement when optimization is requested at compile time.